# Passing a variable from combobox to called function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to pass a variable from a tkinter combobox to a function called when clicking a 'Run' button.  I am relatively new to python and every option I have tried creates an error - mostly that the variable is not defined.  I believe this is because I am not defining it in the correct place.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from URL_Generator import crawl_site

listFile = open('regions1.txt','r')

root = Tk()
root.configure()
varItems = StringVar(root, value='')

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create Window Layout"""
        self.label = Label(self, text="List Items").pack()
        self.itemCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 16, textvariable = varItems)
        self.itemCombo.bind("<Return>", self.itemCombo_onEnter)
        self.itemCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.itemCombo_onEnter)
        self.itemCombo['values'] = [l.strip() for l in listFile.readlines()]
        self.itemCombo.pack()
        self.blank = Label(self,text='').pack()

        """I want to pass the value selected in the combobox to the crawl_region() function when pushing Run"""

        self.RunButton = Button(self, text="Run",command = crawl_site.crawl_region(region))
        self.RunButton.pack()

    def itemCombo_onEnter(self,event):
        varItems.set(varItems.get().lower().strip())
        mytext = varItems.get().strip()
        vals = self.itemCombo.cget('values')
        self.itemCombo.select_range(0,END)
        print(mytext)
        region = mytext

        """I want to pass mytext to the function called when pushing Run"""

        if not vals:
            self.itemCombo.configure(values = (mytext,))
        elif mytext not in vals:
            with open('regions1.txt', 'w') as f:
                self.itemCombo.configure(values=vals + (mytext,))
                f.write("\n".join(vals + (mytext,)))
                f.close()
        return 'break'

app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Sample function called (crawl_site.crawl_region()):

```
class crawl_site():
    def crawl_region(region):
        print('passed region '+ str(region))
```

passed region [] is immediately returned, but nothing happens when I make a selection or press the Run button.

Comment: If you get an error, you should show it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -  Thanks for your quick response!  I have edited the question.  In this sample I am not getting an error, but the function is being called without pressing the button and is returning an empty list because no selection has been made yet.  I believe my problem is in the order of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code.
I've created a class property `self.mytext` which is set when the combo button is entered `itemCombo_onEnter`. When the button is pressed the `onRunButton` function is called. if `self.mytext` has been set, it will call the `crawl_region` function with `self.mytext` as an argument.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from URL_Generator import crawl_site

listFile = open('regions1.txt','r')

root = Tk()
root.configure()
varItems = StringVar(root, value='')

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create Window Layout"""
        self.label = Label(self, text="List Items").pack()
        self.itemCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 16, textvariable = varItems)
        self.itemCombo.bind("<Return>", self.itemCombo_onEnter)
        self.itemCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.itemCombo_onEnter)
        self.itemCombo['values'] = [l.strip() for l in listFile.readlines()]
        self.itemCombo.pack()
        self.blank = Label(self,text='').pack()

        """I want to pass the value selected in the combobox to the crawl_region() function when pushing Run"""

        self.RunButton = Button(self, text="Run",command = self.onRunButton)
        self.RunButton.pack()

    def onRunButton(self):
        if self.mytext:
            crawl_site.crawl_region(self.mytext)        

    def itemCombo_onEnter(self,event):
        varItems.set(varItems.get().lower().strip())
        mytext = varItems.get().strip()
        vals = self.itemCombo.cget('values')
        self.itemCombo.select_range(0,END)
        print(mytext)

        self.mytext = mytext
        """I want to pass mytext to the function called when pushing Run"""

        if not vals:
            self.itemCombo.configure(values = (mytext,))
        elif mytext not in vals:
            with open('regions1.txt', 'w') as f:
                self.itemCombo.configure(values=vals + (mytext,))
                f.write("\n".join(vals + (mytext,)))
                f.close()
        return 'break'

app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Your code wasn't working because of this line

```
self.RunButton = Button(self, text="Run",command = crawl_site.crawl_region(region))
```

This immediately calls the method `crawl_region` with the region as an argument and tries to set the callback of the button to the result of that method.

Another way to 'fix' your problem without creating another function would be to use lambda but I think my method is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, especially explaining why my code wasn't working (that is a huge help)!  When I run your corrected code, I get a "NameError: name 'onRunButton' is not defined error.  Could you please help me get past this error?

Comment: @Justin Hill, `onRunButton` is a class method, so you need `self.onRunButton` as a `command` parameter, when you declare a `self.RunButton`.